# merge the duplicate in string and append the value with comma

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have a string of

```
let check = 'test_name=sdf&test_name=dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg';
```

Is there a way in js where i can merge the duplicates and just append the value of it with comma

the output should be

```
test_name=sdf,dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg;
```

any idea how can i do it

this is what i have tried so far

this is the simplfied version

```
test2: function() {
        let test2 = ['val1','val2','val3'];
        let test3 = ['opt1','opt1','opt3'];


        let filter = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {

            let text = test2[i]; // input value
            let val =test3[i]; // option value

            filter += val + '=' + text;

            if (filter.includes(val) === true) {
                filter += ',' + text;
            }

            i !== test2.length-1 ? filter += '&' : '';

        }
        console.log(filter);
    },
```

the output is `opt1=val1,val1&opt2=val2,val2&opt3=val3,val3`

Comment: I do not think so... you may need to parse...?

Comment: edited sorry i just make it more simplefied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string first by `&` and then `map` through values and split them again using `=`, now using `reduce` and `Map` we club the values with same key name, and in the end join them to get the same structure as original string

```js
let check = 'test_name=sdf&test_name=dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg';

let final = check.split('&').map(v=>v.split('=')).reduce((r,[k,v])=>{
  r.set(k, (r.get(k)||[]).concat(v))
  return r
},new Map())


let output = [...final].map(v=>`${v[0]}=${v[1].join(',')}`).join('&')

console.log(output)
```

Comment: sir there is a problem suppose let check = 'test_name=&test_name=&test_last_name=dfg' the output showing is 'test_name=,&test_last_name=dfg' it is supposed to be test_name=&test_last_name=dfg without the comma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211667/merging-the-duplicate-in-string-and-append-it-with-comma-gives-wrong-output

Comment: You need to filter out empty values

Comment: any idea how? can you check the link?

Comment: Changing `v[1].join(',')` to `v[1].filter(Boolean).join(',')` will be enough