# merging the duplicate in string and append it with comma gives wrong output

Tags: javascript

Supposed i have a function that merge the duplicate in string and append the value with comma

```
let check = 'test_name=sdf&test_name=dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg';

let final = check.split('&').map(v=>v.split('=')).reduce((r,[k,v])=>{
  r.set(k, (r.get(k)||[]).concat(v))
  return r
},new Map())


let output = [...final].map(v=>`${v[0]}=${v[1].join(',')}`).join('&')

console.log(output)
```

and the value will be (which is correct)

```
test_name=sdf,dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg
```

my problem is when i test

```
let check = 'test_name=&test_name=&test_last_name=dfg';
```

the output will be

```
test_name=,&test_last_name=dfg // now there is a comma
```

if there is no value the correct output should be

```
test_name=&test_last_name=dfg // no comma
```

and when i test also

```
let check = 'test_name=&test_name=eqwe&test_last_name=dfg';
```

it gives me wrong output which is

```
test_name=,eqwe&test_last_name=dfg
```

the correct should be

```
test_name=eqwe&test_last_name=dfg
```

any idea how can i do it ? thanks

Comment: How about splitting the final result by ',' and checking if the split values are "" or not ?

Naive solution, but this will work I guess.

Comment: You can update the last `map` method to `[...final].map(v=>\`${v[0]}=${v[1].filter(Boolean).join(',')}\`).join('&')` to filter out all the falsey value.

Answer (score 1):

The point at which your problem happens is because:

> test_name=,&test_last_name=dfg // now there is a comma

`test_name` maps to `['', '']`

and in

> test_name=,eqwe&test_last_name=dfg

`test_name` maps to `['', 'eqwe']`.

Which makes sense, you're not stripping any values yet.

Note how in your second example, you still don't want the comma in there, even though there are no duplicate values.

## Skip empty strings

Instead of deduplicating, one thing you can do is filter out all empty strings from your list, either by:

1. In the `reduce` method, Skipping `r.set` if `v === ''`
2. Using `v[1].filter(val => val !== '')` in your string formatter

## Deduplicate?

As I mentioned, from the way you describe your specs, you'll always want to discard empty strings.

If you still want to dedup on top of that, consider:

1. Putting a `Set` as the value of a map instead of a list. It deduplicates for you.
2. Writing your own `unique` function:

```js
/** Returns unique copy of arr in the same order as the elements in arr */
function unique(arr) {
  const set = new Set();

  for (const item of arr) {
    set.add(item);
  }

  return Array.from(set.values());
}
```

Comment: In your deduplicate section, what's the point of `.entries()`? `unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])` will result in `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]`, I doubt that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant `values`. Thanks!

Comment: `.values()` is redundant since it's the same as `[Symbol.iterator]()` on `Set`. You just need `Array.from(set)` or even `[...set]` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

```js
const check = 'test_name=sdf&test_name=dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg';

//  bag will hold our URLencded string in structured form
const bag = new Map();

check.split('&').forEach(kv => {
    let [k,v] = kv.split('=');
    if (bag.has(k)) {
        // if key exists, merge with other value(s)
        bag.set( k, [v].concat(bag.get(k)));
    } else {
        bag.set(k,[v]);
    }
});

// iterate over key+value pairs, joining with '&' and '='
let final = Array.from(bag).map(([k,v]) => {
   // iterate over values, joining with ','
   let token = [k,v.join(',')].join('=');
   return token;
}).join('&');

console.log(final); // test_name=sdf,dfgdfg&test_last_name=dfg
```

Comment: of course i would be remiss if i didn't point out that you can do this natively using DOM methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams